# Prevent Disabling Device Admin Permission on Oneplus and Oppo Phones

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oppo

Can someone provide a working solution for a Device Admin permission issue in my Android app?
The permission works fine on most devices, but it seems to have problems on specific devices like OnePlus and Oppo.

User can disable it from app info -> uninstall -> Shows a dialogue to remove admin permissions -> uninstall app

I have tried searching for solutions online, but haven't found any helpful resources or code examples. I am using `DeviceAdminReceiver` to enable the permission. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.